# Dynamic Memory Allocation Functions- Malloc and Free

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char *p;
p = (char *)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
strcpy(p, "abcdabcd");
printf("%s\n", p);
free(p);
printf("%s\n", p);
return 0;
}
```

I tried running the above code on Ubuntu. Here I am allocating 4 bytes of memory from malloc. I then tried copying 8 bytes into the memory allocated by malloc. I did not get any warning or error. I tried freeing the block of memory and tried using the same memory that was being freed but again no issues at all. It printed the right string. Can someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: Basically its C and its up to you to enforce these things. No CPU time is wasted enforcing it for you because C strongly emphasizes performance.

Comment: Most of the time malloc allocates more memory than you specify. I guess that's the reason your program works.

Comment: The physical memory usually exists in 4kb pages, so probably the malloc implementation consider this and allocates 1 page in your case.

Comment: @strkol, Please provide sources for your assertion.

Comment: @YoussefG., compile the program and strace it, you'll find the following: mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb76e0000. 4096 bytes allocated by malloc()...

Comment: @strkol, while the program may have that, I don't think that is done by malloc.  Try strace on a program without malloc and you will get the same 4096 bytes allocated.  Also, see Spencer Rathbun answer below.

Comment: @strkol Look up what sbrk kernel call does and its relationship to malloc (and memory management/allocation libraries in general).

Comment: @YoussefG., correct! Malloc() uses brk: brk(0)                                  = 0x8346000
brk(0x8367000)                          = 0x8367000. So in this case malloc allocated 0x1000 (4096) bytes

Comment: @strkol  So why do I get the same amount of bytes allocated without a call to malloc?

Comment: @YoussefG., check again, I bet you don't have brk() calls if you comment malloc()

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov, glibc's malloc uses brk or mmap (depending on the requested size) - check the man page. I thought that mmap is used in this case, but I was wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Malloc -> how much memory has been allocated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213356/malloc-how-much-memory-has-been-allocated)

Answer (score 3):

The behavior cannot be meaningfully explained. Your program exhibits *undefined* behavior, meaning that anything can happen. That "anything" also includes the behavior you observed in your experiment, i.e. "printing the right string".

Today it "printed the right string". Tomorrow it might simply crash. Day after tomorrow it might format your hard drive. That's perfectly permissible under the concept of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Aparrently correct operation is in the class of [undefined behaviour].

Answer (score 2):

When a program is started, it is given access to virtual memory through the OS. Usually virtual pages have some minimum size (say 4 kb) and that is the smallest size that they are handled on.

So you request memory with your malloc below this page size, and a whole block is available. *Some/None/All of this block may be used by other programs*. But it is still technically there:

```
1 byte | 1 byte | 1 byte | 1 byte | more memory you don't have....
 ^ char p points here
```

You then start dumping copying a string into the memory *starting at p*. So you get:

```
a | b | c | d | the rest of the chars start dumping into somebody elses space!
```

This overlap is undefined. In other words, we may have unused memory, so everything works **today**. Tomorrow, that physical memory space is held by the OS, and we fail to overwrite it. The day after, we break some other program. The day after that, we seg fault.

As noted by others, C does not watch out for you.

Answer (score 1):

The C language doesn't guarantee any memory checking. Basically, if you write to memory that is not yours (e.g. you write to memory that exceeds the bounds of your array) or if you read from memory that's not yours (e.g. you read from memory you've given up by free-ing it) there is no knowing what will happen.

However, the operating system may or may not prevent you from doing either of these things. Generally, if this happens, you'll get a "Bus Error" or ["Segmentation Fault"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). However, it is also not guaranteed that either of these things will happen.

The best thing to do is to code defensively. Keep track of how long your arrays are and then assert or otherwise check that when you copy into an array you don't exceed the array size.

Another thing you can do is debug. [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is an extremely effective tool for catching problems like the one you describe. It can indicate both situations where you read or write to memory that you haven't malloc'd. It can also identify leaks, such as when you malloc memory and then later forget to free it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it allocates along block alignments, which would be why it gave you some magical extra memory in this case.  Try upping it to a larger byte multiple (eg. 16,64,etc. and it should be more exact, and it *might* segfault if you go beyond it).  Though keep in mind that if the memory after the malloc'd chunk is also part of your program's memory space...then you won't get a segfault either.

In general, as long as you stay in your programs segment of memory then you can happily read/write all you want (at your own peril of course :D).

If you really want to check your program run it with/in 'valgrind'

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who said you've invoked undefined behavior is correct.

The reason it appeared to work correctly is likely a side-effect of the particular implementation of the heap manager on your platform.  For example, many memory managers round up allocations to some convenient size with the smallest size often being 8 or 16 bytes.  You should **never** depend on such implementation details.

Some platforms have tools for trying to catch these types of assumptions while your developing your program.

Answer (score 0):

Like all others have said ,your code results in **undefined** behavior (anything can happen).

***Your heap memory allocator (malloc) is not responsible for the data stored in
the region after you've freed it*** .

Understanding the responsibilities of malloc will help you explain why you are seeing the result , why its incorrect programming practice and why it wont work all the time .

Malloc is a heap memory allocator (_int_malloc and _int_free) in glibc . You can view its code here [http://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#_int_malloc].

> Can someone please explain this behavior ?

A comical example would help clarifying your question quickly.

Consider you are renting a room  (**memory**) from a motel (**sbrk(2)**) that doesnt have keys to any of  its rooms (**memory**)! .
 You go to the receptionist (**malloc**) and ask for a room (**memory**) , she gives you one that is available  , you take the room (**memory**) and use it .
You are done with it and now promise her you arent going to use it again(**freeing**). She makes an entry in her book that your room (**memory**) is free and can be alloted to others . It is her wish entirely to give the room to somebody else or not . 

You come again after sometime to see your room (receptionist doesnt check you) ,you are lucky if you find nobody using the room  (it looks as messy as you had left!)

**The work of the receptionist (malloc) is to allot a room(memory) to you as quickly as possible , trusting that you keep your word after you vacate (free) .Her job is not to prevent you from using any of the rooms (memory) !**

*The owner (kernel) becomes furious (exception) if you access a place that you are not allowed to (read only region).*

Im a newbie and im not sure if its appropriate to answer this way . Let me know if im wrong
I strongly advice you to go through malloc