# How to get the size of dynamically (using malloc or calloc )allocated memory?

Tags: c, size, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [determine size of dynamically allocated memory in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c)
>   [newbie questions about malloc and sizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533519/newbie-questions-about-malloc-and-sizeof)
>   [How can I get the size of an array from a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c)
>
> [Malloc -> how much memory has been allocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213356/malloc-how-much-memory-has-been-allocated?rq=1)

```
int **arrofptr;
arrofptr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 2);
arrofptr[0] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*6144);
arrofptr[1] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*4800);
```

Now i have to know that how many bytes are allocated in arrofptr,arrofptr[0],arrofptr[1]? is there any way to know the size?

if we will print

```
sizeof(arrofptr);
sizeof(arrofptr[0]);
sizeof(arrofptr[1]);
```

then it will print 4

Comment: It's implementation specific at this point. For example when you're in the Linux kernel you can get this information for memory allocated with kmalloc: `stuff = kmalloc(1,GFP_KERNEL); printk("I got: %zu bytes of memory\n", ksize(stuff));`  Obviously that only works within the Linux kernel, you'd need to get an answer tied to the malloc implementation you're using.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to find how much memory a pointer is referring to.

At least not on any system, so no portable way.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not without using extra data somewhere that stores the allocated sizes.

Comment: Thanks...
Yup you are right we can use structure to track the size....